# fopen returns false when trying on some https urls

Tags: php, ssl, https, http-status-code-400

The following code returns false on some https urls, but it works fine using http urls. The url `https://www.google.com/` will return true, while the url used in the code for example will return false.

PHP configuration:

- openssl enabled: yes
- http wrapper: yes
- https wrapper: yes

PHP code:

```
$proxySettings  = array(
    "http" => array(
        "proxy" => "tcp://example.proxy",
        "request_fulluri" => TRUE,
        "timeout" => 3.0,
        "protocol_version" => 1.0
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($proxySettings);
$fp_ssl  = fopen("https://any-sms.biz/", "r", FALSE, $context);
```

This is the error I get when using https urls that dont work.

> Warning: fopen(https://any-sms.biz/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

How can I use fopen on any https url? Where is my error?

Thank you

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect any-sms.biz:443 -tls1 -servername any-sms.biz` works fine, as does `echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: any-sms.biz\r\n\r\n" | openssl s_client -connect any-sms.biz:443 -tls1 -servername any-sms.biz`. I'm guessing your proxy is misconfigured or broken. Also note: `any-sms.biz` does *not* appear to support TLS 1.2 (`-tls1_2` option).

Comment: HTTP is a higher level protocol. If you get HTTP 400, it means the ssl/tls connection was established.

Comment: When using cUrl, the status code is 200, however "ssl_verify-result" is 0. So it seems like the connection was, indeed, established. But why is fopen failing?